# actual time complexity of merge sort

Tags: algorithm, time, mergesort

I believe I have understood merge-sort to some extent and I was trying to understand the time complexity of merge-sort but find it hard to totally understand it. so we will recursively call mergesort to each(i.e. left and right sub-arrays), which will be log(n) and I understand that. but the merging part of the merge-sort says its complexity is o(n) making the whole time complexity, **O(nlog(n))**. but i don't quite understand how the merging part is linear becasue for every subarray call, there will be len(sub_array) * some constant operations. so if the length of the array to be sorted is n, then the merging part will be as ff according to my understanding:
let k = number of primitive operations, n = length of sub-array, then total time complexity will be, here 2 is as there are two parts(left sub-array and right sub-array).
2(k)*2 + 2(k)*4+2(k)*8 + ......+2(k)n.(number of sums is logn times) but i don't know how is this generalized to nlogn?(like had it been k + k + k + k +.....+k n times, then it makes sense to say O(nk) and discard the constant k, however, in merge sort, it's not constant? so how is the time complexity really computed??

Answer (score 1):

Let array length is n=2^k for simplicity. I'll show scheme for length 8 array.

At first we recursively divide array to 2^(k-1) chunks, then 2^(k-2) chunks and so on until length becomes 1

```
 a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h
```

Now we perform merging to size 2 chunks  (ab denotes sorted array with a and b elements)

```
 a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h
  \ /     \ /     \ /     \ /
   ab     cd       ef      gh
```

We make 4*2 operations (not elementary operations, but every is O(1))

```
   ab     cd       ef      gh
     \   /           \    /
     abcd             efgh
```

We make 2*4 operations

```
     abcd           efgh
          \        /  
           abcdefgh
```

And here we make  1*8 operations

We can see that we make `log(n)` steps, every steps takes the same number: `n` operations, so overall complexity is `O(nlogn)`

Comment: Exactly. We make log(n) passes over all n items. Thus, n log n.